# dd cloned Windows disk to new SSD – boot from clone with error "windows/system32/winload.efi" missing

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd, efi

I cloned my old external SSD `/dev/disk2` to my new external SSD `/dev/disk5` on macOS with dd.

When I now try to boot new SSD `/dev/disk5` the error "windows/system32/winload.efi missing" occurs I think because the EFI/boot on that cloned disk `/dev/disk5` points to content on disk `/dev/disk2`. I can also prove that by also putting in disk `/dev/disk2` and boot from disk `/dev/disk5` which works since the missing file (on disk `/dev/disk2`) got found.

So how do I tell disk `/dev/disk5` boot to use content from disk `/dev/disk5`? I think there need some sort of identifier to get fixed on disk `/dev/disk5` boot partition.

I can use macOS, linux or Windows to fix that boot issue. Whatever is the easiest.

**Update**

Used dd command (to clone the entire disk – not only a single partition for sure)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=/dev/disk5 status=progress bs=64K
```

And the output of `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *512.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI WINTOUSB                104.9 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data WIN                     512.0 GB   disk2s2



/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk5
   1:                        EFI WINTOUSB                104.9 MB   disk5s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data WIN                     512.0 GB   disk5s2
                    (free space)                         488.1 GB   -
```

**Update 2**

Now I got the windows logo after using recovery prompt and some `bcdboot` commands. But after that again a blue screen with `INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE`

Comment: Can you show us the exact dd command you used?

Comment: You apparently cloned the *partitions*, not the entire disk, so you missed out on the EFI partition which is where the boot is done, or you missed out on the boot sector which isn't inside of any partition.

Comment: No I did not – I cloned the entire disk (both partitions got cloned and are able to boot and are complete. The only problem is, that the Boot partition (EFI) points to the other hardware SSDs partition. The new cloned partition showed up as bootable Bootcamp drive in macOS. Updating the question with diskutil list and the used dd command.

Comment: The problem is `disk5s1` boots `disk2s2` and not `disk5s2` what it should boot.